# Can I use multiple elastic search hosts in Spring Bean configuration for multiple elastic search indexes

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing, host, spring-bean

I have a Java API to insert documents to three elastic indexes and it is working. I want to change one index's host in API. Normally, EsConfig file and ElasticSearchTemplate code is ;

```
public class EsConfig {
    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String EsHost;
   @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
   private int EsPort;
   @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
   private String EsClusterName;

   @Bean
   public Client client() throws Exception {
      Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", EsClusterName)
            //.put("index.max_result_window", 4000000)
            .build();

      TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new 
      TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), EsPort));
      return client;
     }

     @Bean
     public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
          ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate = new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
          return elasticsearchTemplate;
      }
```

}

I want to configure this structure to use two hosts together. Is it possible in this structure or should I completely change and remove singleton bean structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch client api allows you to configure multiple host names in the below fashion but unfortunately, they do not work as expected.

According to this [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html#transport-client),

> The TransportClient connects remotely to an Elasticsearch cluster
>   using the transport module. It does not join the cluster, but simply
>   gets one or more initial transport addresses and communicates with
>   them in round robin fashion on each action (though most actions will
>   probably be "two hop" operations).

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));
```

What you can do perhaps is go ahead and implement a Spring Boot concept of [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) where you can create multiple `application.properties`. Below is one of the ways to achieve this.

If I have two different hosts/environments for e.g. `dev` and `prod`, I would end up creating three application properties file (Two for the environments, one properties which would mention which environment you'd want to select).

**application-dev.properties**

```
elasticsearch.clustername = mycluster_name
elasticsearch.host = mydev.abc.com          <-- Configure the name of host 1
elasticsearch.port = 9300
```

**application-prod.properties**

```
elasticsearch.clustername = mycluster_name_2
elasticsearch.host = myprod.abc.com         <-- Configure the name of host 2
elasticsearch.port = 9300
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=dev                 <-- Configure which of the above properties do you want to start application with
```

Now when you run the application as spring boot, it would end up starting the `dev` environment.

Note that I'm assuming that both these nodes are in different clusters and not part of the same cluster. The reason I specify this is because, elasticsearch internally would go ahead and update the replica shards of other nodes if it receives a new/updated document. Being in same cluster, it wouldn't matter which host in a cluster you are pointing to.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, I need to use three different clusters and also hosts at the same time. If I use dev/prod properties, Is it use both of them or select depending on the starting type? 
Another way, I found out, I can triple Elasticsearchtemplate clients but in this solution, I need to implement and override all find/update/delete methods.

For now, I splitted the project to three separate projects for each cluster :)